# Django Storage Backend for local development that proxies to live site?

Tags: python, django

I have to work on several projects with huge amounts of user-generated media files. In the past, I rsynced the content every couple of days, but my local development machine fills up more and more with data that is, for the most part, not needed.

I remember reading about a [storage backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/) that would proxy local file access to the live site, but I can't for the life of me find it anymore.

BTW: I can't simply mount the media directory through ssh/smbfs, since I don't want development code to delete  or damage live data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and created one. Very limited ATM but it works.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-localdevstorage/

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the answer you're looking for, but could you not mount the data read only through ssh/smbfs. Gets you easy access to it, but protects you from damaging it.

Comment: I do things like thumbnailing that need to modify the user generated files, so I need write access to the files, unfortunately.